# SQL join of multiple queries using CTE

Tags: sql

```
WITH group1 AS 
(    
    SELECT 
        [column1],
        [column2]   
    FROM 
        table1
),
Group2 AS 
(
    SELECT
        (column3),  
        COUNT(column3) 
    FROM
        table 2 AS Count   
    WHERE
        (year (date_value) = 2018 and month(Date_vaLue) = 2)
    GROUP BY
        column2
)
SELECT *
FROM group1
JOIN group2 ON group1. table1 = group2.table2;
```

I get an error:

> No column name was specified for column 2 of 'group2'

As this isn't a column and is just an identifier I am confused why it thinks the code `(Group2 AS (Select (column3 ),)` is a column.

I am new at sql so this might just be a silly error

`Column 1` is a name and column two is a unique key for that name

`Column 2` and `column 3` contain the same exact data and I am simply trying to show the number of times it occurs in the DB on the column 3 table, including 0, and relate it back to column 1.

Each datapoint in `column 3` contains only data from `column2`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: I think the parens are messing with column names. You need an alias for the count either way.

Comment: `column 2` is the second column in the select list for group2 which is `COUNT(column3)` for which you need to provide a name so either `Column3Count = COUNT(column3)` or `COUNT(column3) as Column3Count`.  Generic names don't mix well with error messages as you can be confused as to what is it referencing.

Comment: because I am extremely new to sql, and the issue was "as count" was missing from the select statement from in group 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to name the column COUNT(column3) , so...

```
Group2 AS (Select (column3 ),
COUNT (column3) as cntr
From table 2 as Count
Where (year (date_value) = 2018 and month(Date_vaLue) = 2)
Group by column2
)
```

Comment: Turned up I was missing "as count" in the next line. Now I am getting the error from the following.                                                                                                  
SELECT *
FROM group1

JOIN group2 ON group1. table1 = group2.table2                                                                                                        where the table1 and table2 are errors saving invalid column name, when it is structured db.table in both and work in the above

Answer (score 0):

There are so many errors in that query, I don't know where to start

In a cte each column must have a name. `select columnname` makes the resulting column named `columnname`. An aggregation function like `count` does not set a column name, so your second column in your second cte does not have a name, as the error states. Use

```
SELECT column, count(othercolumn) AS ctcol ...
```

You can't add columns you don't use in the grouping to your select list without an aggregation function. Furthermore you can't add a column aggregated and unggregated to the select list. But I suppose, that's only a typo

```
SELECT column2, COUNT(column3) AS ctcol
FROM tablexy
...
GROUP BY column2
```

Your cte don't have any columns named `table1` or `table2`, so your join won't work. Use column named from the cte

```
SELECT * FROM group1 JOIN group2 ON group1.column2 = group2.column2
```

Comment: Yes I do. These are generic names. Table refers to the actual table name in the DB. Column1,2,3 refers to an actual column with a completely separate name in the table1 or table 2. I will try changing the column name to the join instead of the table. I am really new to sql and have problems with syntax.